# Who pays when receiving international calls on a local Canadian mobile number?

Tags: canada, cellphones, communication, roaming

I have no landline and have a Bell account for my cell. I live in Canada and am expecting a call from a friend in Australia.
Will I be charged to receive the call from Australia on my cell on my free wknds?

Comment: I was tempted to flag as off-topic, but I'm giving this question the benefit of the doubt: it can happen that one wishes to communicate with friends and relatives travelling abroad. Therefore I deem this to be a borderline valid Travel question.

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3982/cost-for-us-cell-phone-users-to-receive-international-calls?rq=1

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not travel-related.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the terms of your cellphone plan of course, but all plans I know of in Canada basically work the same way when it comes to your situation: You will pay for the airtime minutes (same as you would pay for a local incoming call at the same time / day - which may be zero depending on your plan and the time / day, e.g. your weekend situation), and your friend in Australia would pay the regular long distance fee to Canada (same fee that would apply if your friend would call a Canadian landline). But if in doubt call *611 (free call) for Bell customer service and ask them.

Comment: I just called them and they confirmed what you said. Nov 2017